# how to do junit testing in android

Tags: android

i am new to android and i want to do a junit testing in android then i followed this code [from android site](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html)

i am getting many errors 
as **HelloAndroid cannot be resolved to a type**

**Multiple markers at this line
    - HelloAndroid cannot be resolved to a type
    - The constructor ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2(Class) refers to the missing type 
     HelloAndroid**

**Multiple markers at this line
    - The method getActivity() from the type ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 refers to the missing type 
     HelloAndroid
    - HelloAndroid cannot be resolved to a type**

**Multiple markers at this line
    - HelloAndroid cannot be resolved to a type
    - com.example.helloandroid.R cannot be resolved to a 
     variable**

```
 package  com.example.helloandroid.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroidTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HelloAndroid> {
    private HelloAndroid mActivity;  // the activity under test
    private TextView mView;          // the activity's TextView (the only view)
    private String resourceString;

    public HelloAndroidTest() {
      super("com.example.helloandroid", HelloAndroid.class);
    }
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = this.getActivity();
        mView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.helloandroid.R.id.textview);
        resourceString = mActivity.getString(com.example.helloandroid.R.string.hello);
    }
    public void testPreconditions() {
      assertNotNull(mView);
    }
    public void testText() {
      assertEquals(resourceString,(String)mView.getText());
    }
}
```

can anyone help me

Comment: a good starting point is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html and http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html After that you will probably have to checkout some of the popular frameworks as Robolectric

Comment: what's the name of the package you work in? Have you paid attention to this line: super("com.example.helloandroid", HelloAndroid.class);

Comment: thankss, but i had followed those links only but these errors are coming into my project

Comment: package name is package **com.example.helloandroid.test;**

Comment: can you include your package declaration and import clauses in the code, just for completion.

Comment: according to the tutorial, you are missing an import of the helloWorld.class. and this class is prerequisite for the TestingTutorial. Do you have the HelloWorld class in your project? And by HelloWorld, I mean - HelloAndroid...

Comment: yes it consists the sample code which is by default generated by android

Answer (score 0):

Too little space in the comments to show you my point...

One of the things you're missing (seeing your code) is the import section:

Your import section:

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Tutorials import section:

```
import com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Also the tutorial says:

> This tutorial and its code depend on the Hello World tutorial. If you
>   haven't completed that tutorial already, do so now. You will learn the
>   fundamentals of Android application development, and you will have an
>   Android application that is ready to be tested. The tutorial guides
>   you through the setup of an Android test project using the ADT Plugin
>   for Eclipse and other SDK tools. You will need an SDK development
>   platform that is version 1.5 (API level 3) or higher.

Make sure you have completed [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) first. Compare your HelloAndroid class with the *final* version in the HelloWorld tutorial. Happy coding!

Comment: i have created a sample code like helloandroid and helloandroidtestwith 2 projects

Comment: when i imported this statement its saying The import com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid cannot be resolved **import com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid;** i have a class in this as HelloAndroid.java

Comment: are those both in 1 project, or in 2 separate projects?

Comment: seperate projects with different package names

Comment: how to set target to helloworld project

Comment: i have used two packages should i have to give any permissions in the manifest file

Comment: How to set the target is explained in step 2 in the "Create Test Project" section of the "Hello, Testing" tutorial.

Comment: Just start over from the Hello World tutorial and repeat all the steps exactly. Everything should work (if your environment is setupped correctly). That would be my final response, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same example it worked for me

I guess in the code

```
 public HelloAndroidTest() {
    super("com.example.helloandroid", HelloAndroid.class);
    }
```

instead of `HelloAndroid.class`  you should put the class name in my case it was `MainActivity`
I changed it to `MainActivity.class` and it worked

Check for the class you are testing and change the `<HelloAndroid>` to the class name `i.i MainActivity`